# Does selenium webdriver support Struts 2

Tags: selenium, struts2, webdriver

I want to use `Selenium WebDriver API` using `Struts2` Framework. So will it be supported or not.

If not then what should I do.

It means, suppose I have an `textfield` on my `jsp`, linked with action class and I want search on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) with my `textfield` value by `sendKeys` to element "q".

What am trying to do is

index.jsp :

```
<s:form action="test">
<s:textfield name="search" label="Enter Search "></s:textfield>
</s:form>

</body>
```

struts.xml:

```
    <action name="test" class="com.actions.TestAction">
          <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

ActionClass :

```
package com.actions;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{

    private String search;

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1241657564582564726L;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));


        element.sendKeys(getSearch());

        element.submit();


        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());


        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());        

        driver.quit();
        return "SUCCESS";
    }


}
```

Error :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:428)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

eagerly waiting for your replies. 
Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Until someone comes along with a better answer... I've never used struts directly but I think I have a basic idea of what it does.

Selenium operates on the front end, as the user would. I believe struts is a back-end only technology, which means that the browser doesn't even know it's receiving something assembled by struts. Struts just helps the server assemble the html, css, and javascript.

Selenium operates well with html, javascript, and css, and since that's what your server is sending out, it should all be good, it should "support it" just fine!